# python apscheduler not shutting down

Tags: python, python-2.7, apscheduler

I'm trying to stop the apscheduler from running on by removing the `job` and shutting it down completely!

None of them is working, my function `expire_data` still gets triggered

```
def process_bin(value):
    print "Stored:",pastebin.value
    print "Will expire in",pastebin_duration.value,"seconds!"

    if pastebin_duration>=0:
        scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
        job=scheduler.add_job(expire_data, 'interval', seconds=5)
        scheduler.start()
        job.remove()
        scheduler.shutdown()

def expire_data():
    print "Delete data!"
```

How can I stop it?

Comment: Please tag with *either* python 2 or 3.

Comment: sorry, fixed, python 2.7!

Comment: Could you please paste a complete working example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: I'm trying to stop the `apscheduler` from running

You are using a `BlockingScheduler`, therefore you can't.

> **APScheduler** [BlockingScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler)

BlockingScheduler is the simplest possible scheduler.
It runs in the foreground, so when you call start(), **the call never returns**.

---

> Read about Choosing the right scheduler

- BlockingScheduler: use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process
- BackgroundScheduler: use when you’re not using any of the frameworks below, and want the scheduler to run in the background inside your application
- AsyncIOScheduler: use if your application uses the asyncio module
- GeventScheduler: use if your application uses gevent
- TornadoScheduler: use if you’re building a Tornado application
- TwistedScheduler: use if you’re building a Twisted application
- QtScheduler: use if you’re building a Qt application