# apscheduler: how to end scheduler after task completed

Tags: python, apscheduler

```
print('hi apscheduler')
def job_task():
    print("Hello ...{}".format(datetime.now()))
sched = BlockingScheduler()
print("adding new job:")
job_id = sched.add_job(job_task, 'interval', minutes=1, start_date='2018-08-30 16:16:00',
                       end_date='2018-08-30 16:18:00', id='my_job_id')
print("added new job to scheduler")
print(job_id)
res = sched.start()
print(res)
print(sched.job_ids())
sched.remove_job('my_job_id')
print("my_job_id job removed")
sched.shutdown()
print(" shutng down the scheduler:")
```

wanted to end the scheduler once the task is completed, but scheduler keeps on running even after end date reached.

Comment: Are you saying that `sched.shutdown()` didn't work, or was never called, or something else?

Comment: yeah correct. after completing job_task, scheduler jobs keeps on running. I want to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer. used wrong type of scheduler. 
for more details follow this link [python apscheduler not shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313801/python-apscheduler-not-shutting-down)